# Converting a Youtube Upload into Podcast

Tags: python, youtube, podcast

There is this youtube channel that uploads one videos per week at exactly the same time every week.
Is it somewhat possible to create a python script that creates a podcast out of it.

What Library should I be learning to make this thing possible or is it even possible in the first place?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. There are legal blah blah blah rights blah blah blah... but you know that already.

I would think if you have a link that auto-plays on page open you could use *[webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html)* with *[PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/)* as a simple way to rip the audio from a youtube video.  This would require you to play the whole thing and doesn't take into account how long the play time is, but it may get you started.

```
""" A wire between input and output. """
import pyaudio
import sys
import webbrowser

# open the page
webbrowser.open(AUTOPLAY_URL)

chunk = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
            channels = CHANNELS,
            rate = RATE,
            input = True,
            output = True,
            frames_per_buffer = chunk)

print "* recording"
for i in range(0, 44100 / chunk * RECORD_SECONDS):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    stream.write(data, chunk)
print "* done"

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

This is just code form the pyaudio page.  I haven't tried to run it but if your lucky it will work.

How to package and serve the resulting audio file is another issue.

Answer (score 2):

[youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/) is a python script that can download YouTube movies in the various available formats. It will also do the audio conversion for you if you have the [lame mp3 library](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) installed